# Py2exe, PyInstaller - openpyxl not found after building exe

Tags: python, python-3.4, py2exe, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I am trying to build a working executable on Windows from my Python script.

- I use Python 3.4
- my script is working perfectly
- I can build the executable with py2exe or pyinstaller
- I am using openpyxl

=> When I run the executable, it closes instantly with this error:

- exe with py2exe:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrix.py", line 10, in 
  File "C:\Program Files\Python_34\lib\site-packages\zipextimporter.py", line 116, in load_module
    raise zipimport.ZipImportError("can't find module %s" % fullname)
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module openpyxl

- exe with pyinstaller:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrix.py", line 10, in 
ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'
Failed to execute script matrix

I tried reinstalling openpyxl multiple times with different methods:

- pip
- setup.py
- easy_install

Still cannot make the executable run.

py2exe compile.py:

```
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

entry_point = sys.argv[1]
sys.argv.pop()
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
sys.argv.append('-q')

opts = {
    'py2exe': {
        'packages':["openpyxl"],
        'compressed': 1,
        'optimize': 2,
        'bundle_files': 1
    }
}

setup(console=[entry_point], options=opts, zipfile=None)
```

Comment: i have the same issue but for the "requests" package.  anyone have a solution for this?